# How to pass generic property in swift?

Tags: swift

Let's assume I have these two models:

```
struct Vegetarian: Menus {
    var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var vegiDishes: [String]?
    var veganDishes: [String]? 
}

struct Vegan: Menus {
    var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var veganDishes: [String]?
}
```

They are both conforms to this protocol:

```
protocol Menus: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String? {get set} 
}

extension Menus {
    var vegiDishes: [String]? {
        get{ return [] } set{}
    }
    var veganDishes: [String]? {
        get{ return [] } set{}
    }
}
```

I have this object:

```
var myMenu: Vegetarian = Vegetarian()
```

If I want to add a dish, I'll do this:

```
addDish(menu: myMenu, dish: "Some Vegetarian Dish")
```

But since the two models have a different type of dishes properties, I'll have to have something like this:

```
func addDish<T: Menus> (menu: T, dish: String) {

    switch menu {
        case is Vegetarian:
            var newMenu: Vegetarian = Vegetarian()
            newMenu.veganDishes?.append(dish)
        case is Vegan:
            var newMenu: Vegan = Vegan()
            newMenu.veganDishes?.append(dish)
        default:
            print("no such type")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify my method so I could specify a property in the call?
Let's say, something like this:

```
addDish(menu: myMenu, dish: "Some Vegetarian Dish", genericProperty: veganDishes)
```

Which will make my method look like this?

```
func addDishGenericProperty<T: Menus> (menu: T, dish: String, genericProperty?) {
    menu.genericProperty.append(dish)
}
```

Comment: Unclear. What on earth is the point of `newMenu` when you've just received a `menu`?

Comment: The above code is only to emphasize what I want to do which is to pass a property when calling a method

Comment: Don't show fake code that you think emphasizes something. Show real code.

Comment: You can certainly "pass a property". It's called a keypath. But I am not convinced that that's what you need to do.

Comment: For your question - I'm creating newMenu because if I'll try to modify menu, it'll shout that "Cannot assign to property: 'menu' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: Then that should be your question.

Comment: These are two question, the first one is more important to me now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems perfect for a key-path! Or more specifically, a [`WritableKeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/writablekeypath).

Since `Vegetarian` is a `struct`, it is a value type. This means we can't just set `vegiDishes` for example and expect that value to be reflected to our `myMenu` from outside the function. Instead you can use `inout` so `myMenu` is changed.

I had to also clear up the `Menus` and the types quite a bit, so they use non-optional arrays instead. If you need to check if the array is empty, use `myMenu.vegiDishes.isEmpty`.

Here is an example of how you can achieve all this:

```
protocol Menus: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String { get }
}
```

```
struct Vegetarian: Menus {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case vegiDishes
        case veganDishes
    }

    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var vegiDishes: [String]
    var veganDishes: [String]

    init(vegiDishes: [String] = [], veganDishes: [String] = []) {
        self.vegiDishes = vegiDishes
        self.veganDishes = veganDishes
    }
}

struct Vegan: Menus {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case veganDishes
    }

    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var veganDishes: [String]

    init(veganDishes: [String] = []) {
        self.veganDishes = veganDishes
    }
}
```

Adding dishes:

```
func addDish<T: Menus>(menu: inout T, dish: String, kind: WritableKeyPath<T, [String]>) {
    menu[keyPath: kind].append(dish)
}


var myMenu: Vegetarian = Vegetarian()
addDish(menu: &myMenu, dish: "Some Vegetarian Dish", kind: \.vegiDishes)
print(myMenu.vegiDishes)
```

> Prints:
>
> ```
> ["Some Vegetarian Dish"]
> ```

Or alternatively, you could literally just do the following if possible in your case:

```
myMenu.vegiDishes.append("Some Vegetarian Dish")
```

Comment: Much better to simply declare your arrays non optional and initialize them with an empty collection. I’ve never needed to declare an array as optional.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah I just kept that from the original question, but probably best to not have them optional. I'll update answer now with a note on checking when it's empty

Comment: Thanks! seems like WritableKeyPath is the direction I need to take. Still struggling with my code, but I'll figure it out from here :)